# Which book follows right after Terminator 2: Judgement Day?

Tags: the-terminator-series

I know there are quite a few  Terminator books out there, but can someone tell me which book is a direct sequel to *Terminator 2: Judgement Day*? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The T2 trilogy is what you're looking for.

The series consists of these three novels:

- T2 - Infiltrator (2001)
- T2 - Rising Storm (2003)
- T2 - The Future War (2004)

The first one has following line in it's summary:

> Following the events of TERMINATOR 2: JUDGEMENT DAY, Sarah and John
>   Conner fled to Paraguay to disappear. But one day Sarah spots an
>   'Arnold' Terminator unit in the town square.

edit: Although there seems to be another trilogy which follows the events of Terminator 2: Judgment Day. It's called The New John Connor Chronicles and consists of these three novels:

- The New John Connor Chronicles: Dark Futures (2002)
- The New John Connor Chronicles: An Evil Hour (2003)
- The New John Connor Chronicles: Times of Trouble (2003)

This trilogy has following line in it's summary:

> Following the events of Terminator 2: Judgment Day, Sarah Connor and
>   John Connor thought they had altered the timeline so that neither the
>   artificially intelligent satellite Skynet nor its Terminator killing
>   machines would ever be created.

I don't know if and how the series are connected.